# How to preview image in monitor

Tags: website-design, print-design, images

I found this nice looking image:

[image]

I have a simple php web site that I also would like to preview in monitor. Is there any tool or wen site that can auto generate this image?

Comment: Just to clarify: you're looking for a way to display your site/web app inside of a monitor/display photo?

Comment: If you want to do this real-time. You can use code to preview the webpage. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145273/how-to-load-an-external-webpage-into-a-div-of-a-html-page. You can also search google for "load external webpage into a div"

Answer (score 4):

There is a website, Woorank that auto generate your website into a monitor like this:

[image]

They offer a 7 day free trial. Very good website if you are a web designer.

You can also do this manually with a program like Photoshop or GIMP.

Open up your image in photoshop or GIMP. Use the the Pen Tool to draw a shape around the screen:

[image]

Then take a screenshot of your website and paste that on-top of the shapes you drew.

You will need to make a clipping mask between the 2 layers (For Photoshop). Hold down Alt (Option in Mac OS), position the pointer over the line dividing two layers in the Layers panel (the pointer changes to two overlapping circles), and then click.

It will look like this:

[image]

The end result:

[image]

I am not sure of other automated websites that can do this for you.